# QMenu icons not scaling down

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

I am adding some QActions to a menu, and I add a QIcon to them

```
QMenu * viewMenu = new QMenu;
viewMenu->addAction(QIcon(":/images/attachment.png"),"Save &Screenshot",this,
 SLOT(onSaveScreenshot()), QKeySequence("Ctrl+P"));
```

The menu small icon size for my style (QClearLooks) is 16x16.
The issue is that when attachment.png is 32x32, the icon won't scale down but appear cropped. If the icon has 16x16 and 32x32 version, the small one is chosen and is displayed properly.

Can't I provide the 32x32 and tell the QMenu to scale down the icon if necessary?